# What is the name of this phenomenon in grammar?

Tags: terminology

> 1 I gave him a wrench. 1a A wrench was given to him. - CORRECT

**Give** can be used in either the active or passive voices.

> 2 We come across different people. - OK 2a Different people can be
> come across by us. - WRONG

**Come across** cannot be used in the passive voice.

---

*What is it called when a verb can be used in the passive and active voices or when it can't?*

Comment: [*Officers and men among the Russian **troops that have been come across** by Sir West Ridgeway's party make no concealment that their faces are set towards India...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Officers+and+men+among+the+Russian+troops+that%22) You might not like it, but there's nothing inherently wrong with "passive" ***to come across***.

Comment: *...Different wrenches **can be given to him by us*** sounds pretty awful to me anyway (we say *We can give him different wrenches*).

Comment: OK. But the point of my question is how this phenomenon is called?

Comment: Google Bard says that among others, ***Intransitive verbs:** These verbs only take a subject and lack a direct object, therefore no entity can be passivized. Examples include "run," "jump," "sleep," "cry," "fall."* But there are a number of reasons why any given verb either can't be "passivised" at all, or doesn't normally work well. There won't be a collective name for all of them, I'm sure.

Comment: ...the fact that Bard seems not to realise a race can be run, or a hurdle jumped, just reminds us AI has some way to go yet. I'm not so sure about *A river was cried by me over you,* though! (And I defy anyone to come up with a syntactically valid passive ***to fall*** :)

Comment: @user1425 You are quite right to say that "come across" doesn't permit a prepositional passive. "We came across some old letters" is fine, but *"Some old letters were come across" is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is any official name but non-passive verbs should be understood.

From Practical English Usage:

> Some transitive verbs, too, are seldom used in the passive. Most of these are 'stative verbs’ (verbs which refer to states, not actions).

From Oxford Learner's Dictionary:

> come across somebody/something

> [no passive] to meet or find somebody/something by chance